# Can I stop an OS X application getting focus after it has loaded?

Tags: macos, application-launch, window-focus

If a program takes some time to load, I like to continue working on something else. But then when that program finishes loading, it gets focus.

Specifically, I am working in Eclipse, and then also start IntelliJ IDEA. Meanwhile I continue working in Eclipse.

Current situation: when IntelliJ IDEA finishes loading, it switches to that screen.

Desired situation: when IntelliJ IDEA finishes loading, it stays behind the window currently focused, and its Dock icon bounces or something to notify me it finished loading, instead of becoming the currently focused window.

How do I make it load in the background and STAY in the background, until I switch to it myself?

Comment: @richard yes this is correct

Comment: @Arjan Eclipse and Intellij Idea -> i am working in eclipse, and i needed intellij Idea, so i clicked it, but I want it to load, and when i'm ready to focus on it, to shift the focus myself.

Comment: @Arjan is it better now ?

Comment: I use Debian (Gnu+Linux+X11+Kde), so this may not apply to you. I have two settings: One for keyboard focus stealing prevention level, one for window placement policy. A lot of this can also be configured on a per application basis. All of this configuration is part of X11+Kde, not part of application.

Comment: __hopefully__ . I'm looking into X11. There's a good chance the ability is available in OSX. I knew it was available on debian based systems. X11 isn't shipped with OSX anymore. This would solve a few of my problems.

Comment: @Arjan which richard's comment ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this for individual applications by going to `Show Package Contents`, editing `Info.plist`, and adding this to the file:

```
<key>LSBackgroundOnly</key>
<string>True</string>
```